# Вместо client authority показывается Don't change these at runtime в Network Transform (Unreliable)

Tags: unity3d, unity-mirror

Я смотрел гайды по mirror и везде отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я добавляю скрипта на игрока у меня отбражается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Очевидно, гайды написаны для более старой версии.